# Как организовать кросс доменный запрос в yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, cross-domain

Вроде ничего сложного в задаче нет, но не могу найти встроенные механизмы, для того, чтоб послать запрос из php кода на другой сайт. Принимать - без проблем [вот таким образом](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/incoming-post.md), а как послать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

при помощи `file_get_contents()`

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://google.ru');
```

при помощи `curl()`

```
    $arrayPostRequest = array (
        'name' => 'test'
    );

    $curl = curl_init('https://google.ru');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($arrayPostRequest));
    $out = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $out;
    curl_close($curl);
```

или вам наоборот нужно?

upd январь 2019 года:
 В действительности есть у yii встроенная библиотека yii\httpclient\Client

Comment: Я думал, что в yii2 есть встроенный механизм, но его не оказалось. Спасибо за ответ, возможно он будет кому-то полезен. Я установил расширение для этого.

Comment: @naumov только не `http_query_build`, а `http_build_query` )

Comment: @naumov ну раз уже подняли тему, то от разработчиков Yii давно вышла библиотека yii\httpclient\Client. С ним мне кажется намного удобней работать.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev Ох, да уже прошло столько времени, библиотек были и тогда, Guzzle например. Но для большинства случаев хватает `file_get_contents('https://google.ru', $context);` где в contexte запрос.